# Seat tube dents from Front Derailleur band-on. Is this gonna get worse over time?

Tags: frames, damage

I just noticed it on the seat tube yesterday.

Looks like a front derailleur clamp mark though I'm running a 1x setup (my LBS might've tried something on it before I purchased).

Just worried about the structural integrity and safety of the frame. I mean if it's not gonna be worse, I can live with it.

It's a VO PolyValent Gen4, btw.

[image]

Comment: VO = VeloOrange?

Comment: @PaulH https://velo-orange.com/pages/polyvalent-gen-4  looks like it

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if the bike was new when you purchased it I'd call this unacceptable. No matter whether it's probably or maybe almost certainly going to hold up...

Comment: @user2705196 I totally agree. But if I return this, I'd probably have to wait for 1-2 months since this is my LBS's last PolyValent in my size and they don't have any other framesets that could fit me. You live & learn, I guess. Lol

Answer (score 7):

It's fine, no issue at all on a 4130 bike. Could have been caused by putting an FD on a weird diameter tube that was close to but not quite 28.6. It's safe to ignore.

Comment: Thanks, Nathan! Will try to ignore.

Comment: Yep. I've seen folks ride around for years on steel frames with major dents in the top or seat tubes with no issue. This is nothing

Comment: Agreed, and it’s in a very low risk location.

Answer (score 4):

Hard to say what will happen, but it does look like an aggressively tightened bandon strap front derailleur.  Unusual that it had enough clamping force to distort a frame tube - must have been phenomenally tight and fitted by a gorilla.

I think the best thing to do is keep an eye on it, and if things change or get worse, then stop riding and re-evaluate.

If the bike is brand new, it may be worth a warranty claim.  If you've had it a while, then that is unlikely to fly.

The other possibility is that these frames have a pre-crimped mark to help wiht assembly of the front mech - can you look at another one to see if they all have the same mark?  I've seen similar on some models, with clearance dents on chainstays etc.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I already spoke to VO about this. They pretty much said the same thing and added that there's also a possibility that it's just smushed paint from a derailleur. 

I've been trying to run my fingers on the spot since last night and I'm really having a hard time figuring out if it's really a dent or what. 

Anyway, I'll try my best to live with it. Lol

Comment: @flout2514 If the visual aspect of the dent is annoying, either fit a chain keeper there, or perhaps find a small decal to stick on that spot.

Comment: yeah, it's a little bit annoying but I think I should be over it knowing it's not really a big deal. I was just making sure it's not gonna worsen over time, that's all. Really appreciate your inputs though, man!

Comment: Sure looks dented to me, from the shadows, but I doubt it will ever cause a problem